# Why does bool casting is called?

Tags: c++, boolean, overloading, this, operator-keyword

Why is `bool` casting being called ?

The problem appears when the constructor `Set result(*this)` is called. I expect it to use the Copy Constructor, instead it casts `*this` to `bool` and uses it as an `int` for the constructor.

How to fix it to use the copy constructor?

```
Set Set::operator+(const Set& rhs)const
{
    Set result(*this);

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < rhs.getSize(); i++)
    {
        result.add(rhs[i]);
    }
    return result;
}

Set::operator bool()const
{
    return !!(*this);
}

Set::Set(size_t capacity)
{
    data = new int[capacity];
    size = 0;
    this->capacity = capacity;
}

void Set::copy(const Set& copied)
{
    size = copied.getSize();
    capacity = copied.getCapacity();
    if (data != nullptr)
        delete[]data;
    data = new int[capacity];
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        data[i] = copied.getAt(i);
}

Set::Set(Set& copied)
{
    copy(copied);
}

Set& Set::operator=(const Set& copied)
{
    if (this != &copied)
        copy(copied);
    return *this;
}

int& Set::getAt(unsigned int idx)const
{
    if (idx < 0 || idx >= size)
        throw "Invalid index\n";

    return data[idx];
}

bool Set::operator !()const
{
    if (size == 0)
        return true;
    return false;
}
```

Comment: I have provided the copy constructor , it uses the copy method. !!(*this) is not recursive. !(*this) returns true or false and I negate it using ! .

Comment: I just added the impl of operator !

Answer (score 5):

The argument for your copy constructor `Set::Set(Set& copied)` is not a `const` reference. The operator `Set Set::operator+(const Set& rhs)const` is `const` so `this` is a `const Set *` and `*this` is a `const Set`. Since you cannot pass a `const T` to a `T&` argument (it would discard the `const`) you may not make use of the copy constructor in this context.

To fix this, make your copy constructor accept `const Set &` instead, just like the `copy` member function does :

```
Set::Set(const Set& copied)
//       ^^^^^ Added const here
{
    copy(copied);
}
```

Edit : Mandatory disclaimer that you should not have to write your own dynamically sized array. Use [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) instead. It will greatly simplify your type and will probably be far safer.

Comment: Thank you. That fixed it.
Now when the return is reached it throws exception because of the delete[]data in the copy method called by the copy constructor .

Comment: @DianIvanov I can't tell for sure what the problem is, but you probably didn't respect the [rule of 3/5/0](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three). If you need a custom copy constructor you probably need to write your own copy assignment operator (`Set & operator=(const Set &)` and destructor as well.

Comment: @DianIvanov That's assuming you can't use `std::vector<int>` for `data`. If you can, use the `vector`. It'll make darn near everything you do here far, far easier.

Comment: I have operator = . I didn't want to dilute the Question. But I will upload the impl of op=.

Comment: Thank you guys but this code is for training and the lecturer doesn't want us to use vecor for the training

Comment: @DianIvanov Further problems with your code are beyond the scope of this question.

Answer (score 1):

You can declare casting operator explicit to avoid implicit casting to bool:

```
explicit operator bool() const {
    ...
}
```

And then use it like this:

```
Set::bool(//obj_name);
```